# Serialize an instance of a Fragment

Tags: c#, android, json, android-fragments, serialization

So I'm using the Newtonsoft JSON serializer in Visual Studio 2015 programming for Android with Xamarin..I want to serialize a fragment to store it in a sql database. The fragment is inheriting from Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment and at the point where I'm trying to serialize, the object has already been created and the layout was inflated as well. I'm also relatively new to developing for Android and C# and .NET, so I could be making major blunders elsewhere.

The class is a bit too big to post here, it holds a lot of other objects such as Buttons, ImageViews and some other data types. All the fields are private but I've also tried this by making public properties for them. I've tried with and without [Serializable] although I don't think that has anything to do with json.

So the event that triggers this eventually tries to run:

```
var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mMemoriesFragment);
Console.WriteLine("Length: " + test.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Data: " + test);
```

and each time the value is returned 2, which is just "{}"

The Json serializer is working fine for mock classes that have properties, but always returns with no values when I try to serialize the fragment. Is there any specific trick to this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?